# Entity Framework 5, Code First Lazy Loading Not Working

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to get my head around EF, and have hit a hurdle, i'm using the simple blog/post structure and have created the classes, for example:

```
''' <summary>
''' Represents a blog in the database
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class Blog
    Public Property BlogID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' All posts in this blog
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property BlogPosts As List(Of BlogPost)
End Class
```

Now if I do this

```
    Using db As New DBContext
        _blog = db.Blogs.
            FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.BlogID = BlogID)

        Dim _posts = _blog.BlogPosts.First
    End Using
```

I get a null reference exception on BlogPosts, it isn't lazy loading.

Now I can force it to work using .Include, but that defeats the object.

All the c# examples I find declare there BlogPosts property with "Virtual", I don't know what the VB version of that would be?  For example:

```
public virtual ICollection<BlogPosts> BlogPosts { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the property Overridable sorted it

Answer (score 0):

Use the overrides keyword, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802201/vb-net-overridable-property-not-same-as-c-sharp-virtual-property).

That should do the trick.